# Moment localization not considering time while formating date?

Tags: javascript, angular, momentjs, angular10, moment-timezone

```js
function formatedDate (localid, inputdate) {
 var locale = 'es_MX';
     console.log(locale, inputdate)
     // Set locale to moment
      moment.locale(locale);
     // Get locale data
     const localeData = moment.localeData(locale);
     const format = localeData.longDateFormat('L');
     const m2 = moment(new Date(inputdate), format);
     console.log(m2.format());
     console.log(m2.format(format) + ' using format: ' + format);
return m2.format(format)
};

 

console.log(formatedDate('ex-MX', '2020-10-07T06:02:55Z'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

I need to convert dates according to the country/area , it depends completely base on location.

So I am trying to achieve this by using moment js

Here dates are stores in UST format in database

Example: If Input ''2020-10-07T09:30:00'

expected Output for 06/10/2020

Here date is formatting according to the locale but it not considering time, all regions it showing same date in different formats, based on time and locale it should format..

Note: I only need to display date (but while formatting time should consider)

In my angular application it not working as expected What I am doing wrong ,, Can any one help me .

Thanks in advance

Comment: We had a lot of problems with moment in our project. We switched to Luxon. Maybe it could help you.

Comment: Can you add the current result and the expected result to your question?

Comment: @james I Update my expected output

Answer (score 1):

```
function formatedDate (localid, inputdate) {
     const local = moment(inputdate).locale(localid)
     return local.format('L')
};

 

console.log(formatedDate('ex-MX', '2020-10-07T06:02:55Z'));
```

if you want local time based on timezone, use moment-timezone

```
   function formatedDate(date,timezone){
      return moment.tz(date,timezone).format('LLLL');
   }
```

Comment: How to get timezone ?

Comment: you can use moment-timezone to guess user timezone as well
        
const clientTimezone = moment.tz.guess(true);
        
You can also find browser locale using
        
const locale = window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language;

Answer (score 0):

Locale does not relate to a timezone because one locale may belong to multiple timezones. For example, `en-US` has 6 timezones. So I don't think passing a locale will convert your date to the expected timezone.

You can use [DatePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe) provided by angular for formatting and timezone conversions.

If your date is in `UST`, you can convert it to `UTC` by adding 4 hours. Then convert it to your required timezone -

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
 zone = 'IST';
 locale = 'en-US'; 
 currentDate = '';
  constructor(private date: DatePipe) {

  }
  getTime() {
    // Date is in UTC (suffix z)
    const d = this.date.transform('2020-10-07T09:30:00Z', 'short', this.zone, this.locale);
    console.log(d);
    this.currentDate = d;
  }
```

Please see [this example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-momentjs-5rwzth?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

**Note**:

I am not sure if you have the timezone available, but you can always get it if you know the location (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16086964/3503019) answer).

Comment: As per requirement I need to localized dates for maximuz all conunties 

so I take locale language code using browser navigator.language

Angular I tried ,,
 in  angular how to import all language locals from common modules??

Can you suggest

Comment: What is the exact problem? Is it the timezone conversion or getting the locale from browser? See this article to know how to get user's location if he/she allows one - https://medium.com/@balramchavan/display-and-track-users-current-location-using-google-map-geolocation-in-angular-5-c259ec801d58